# Only a few characters of an arabic word in a different color

Tags: color, arabic

Can we get for example only the last character of an arabic word written in a red color.

I use the arabi package with pdfLatex

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146380/8528)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc} % from the arabi package to get the colored short vowel

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\newcommand{\ARtextcolor}[2]{\LR{\textcolor{#1}{\RL{#2}}}}
\allowarab{\ARtextcolor}


\begin{document}

\setarab
\Large
\newsavebox{\uu}
\savebox{\uu}{\textcolor{red}{u}}


\begin{RLtext}
'an-\nospace\ARtextcolor{red}{-ta} \ARtextcolor{red}{ta-} \nospace -f`al \hspace{-3pt} \LR{\usebox{\uu}}

'an-\nospace\ARtextcolor{blue}{-ti} \ARtextcolor{blue}{ta-} \nospace -f`al- \nospace\ARtextcolor{blue}{-yna}
\end{RLtext}

\end{document}
```

[image: sortie]