# Coloring Arab vowels/marks without losing connection

Tags: xetex, symbols, color, arabic, arabxetex

In Arabic script you add short vowels/diacritics (marks) above/below the consonants. How do yo go about coloring them (on a case by case basis) without losing connection/breaking the letters/vowels in a word?

In the MWE below I'm trying to color the letter `b` in the (transliterated) word `balad` without also coloring `a` that stands above the consonant in the word.

Lastly, in the small sample below I manage to get a work solution by adding an extension/prolongation to the letter `b` (using `_` and adding to this the 'zero width join' unicode character `\char"200D` suffix), but this is somewhat a hack and adds unnecessary (and unwanted) strokes to the text.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\let\textarabic\relax      % required for polyglossia/arabxetex
\let\Arabic\relax          %
\setotherlanguages{arabic}

\begin{document}

1. 
\begin{arab}[voc]
balad
\end{arab}

2. 
\begin{arab}[voc]
\textcolor{red}{b_}\char"200D alad
\end{arab}


\end{document}
```

I found this ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280791/192642)) old post using `pdfLaTeX`, with the package `arabtex` and style `acolor.sty`, solving it in a more generic manner (where all vowels/marks are colored). However I can't seem to get this working in the MWE above, and unsure if this solution for `arabtex` also will work with the above MWE in `arabxetex`

*Typing in `XeLaTeX` with `memoir` in Overleaf.*

Answer (score 2):

`arabluatex` is able to do this.  Of course, you need to use `lualatex` to compile your document.  Please refer to the documentation ([currently sec. 7 on p. 35](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/arabluatex/arabluatex.pdf#section.7)) for more information.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabluatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{arab}
  \arbcolor[red]{b}.alad
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Spot in, that's the result I'm looking for. However, it's always a tradeoff between ```LuaLaTeX``` (```arabluatex```) and ```XeLaTeX``` (```arabxetex```), and for the project at hand, I'm typing it in the later, i.e.  ```XeLaTeX``` with packages ```arabxetex``` and ```polyglossia```. Looking for a working solution with this setup.

Comment: I get your point.  Using the taṭwīl should get you out of trouble easily, but with a somewhat poor visual result.  As for the zero width joiner, depending on the font you are using, you may get unwanted additional marks printed. (But I haven't tested this solution under `xelatex`)

Comment: I have tried the same setup in XeLaTeX without a positive result. ```\arabcolor{}``` is not a predefined command in ```arabxetex```, and manually coloring (and using the syntax with ```.```) breaks the stroke of the word.

Comment: Yes, `\arbcolor{}` and `.a .u .i` input scheme are specific to `arabluatex`.  Besides, Lua is needed to color nodes as `arabluatex` does.

Comment: @imdk4242 You might be interested in [reading this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84007)

Comment: I link to the same link in the question. Somehow, if you follow the comment thread, they manage to solve this, but seems to be in arabtex and not with XeLaTeX

Comment: @imdk4242 Indeed.  And you are correct: `acolor.sty` is for `arabtex`.  Regarding `arabxetex`, I fear that Khaled Hosny's answer applies.  You might want to ask him directly.

Comment: I'm quite new to TEXSE, how do I go about writing/tagging a specific person

Comment: @imdk4242 Go to Hosny's answer, and add a new comment below.  Remember to include his username in your comment, by typing, say: `@kh`..., wait for the autocompletion to operate, and add a space, just as I did here.  He will be notified.

Comment: Oh, it seems that I'm too novice to have that future enabled, need 50 reps (got 47) before I can comment on other posts. A bit styched here

Comment: @imdk4242 Well, then! I'll do it for you right away!

Comment: @imdk4242 I just did, but for some reason, the `@` mechanism didn't work there.  Let's wait for a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not perfect with all arabic letters and in all the situations but it is just a start:

`\def\red#1#2{\hspace{5pt}\char"200D #2\hspace{-5pt}\textcolor{red}{#1-}-}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\let\textarabic\relax      % required for polyglossia/arabxetex
\let\Arabic\relax          %
\setotherlanguages{arabic}


\def\red#1#2{\hspace{5pt}\char"200D #2\hspace{-5pt}\textcolor{red}{#1-}-}
\begin{document}

\begin{arab}[voc]
balad

\red balad


\end{arab}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried this out, and as you can see (in the picture you uploaded), the stroke after the first letter ```b``` is prolonged compared with the above one with no color. So the trick is to get the (2.) to look identical with the (1.) AND only coloring the first letter (without the mark/vowel).

Comment: @imdk4242 answer updated. that's all what I get!

Comment: I truly appreciate the input, however this hack is not a scalable solution, and won't work. The MWE is exactly that, it shows the single Arabic letter B in its initial position for illustrative purposes... I need to color different letters in different position with different short vowels/diacritics (marks).

Comment: @imdk4242 sorry!