# How to typesetting traditional Arabic texts

Tags: context, arabic, arabtex, arabxetex, arabluatex

I was researching how to typeset traditional Arabic texts in LaTeX and stumbled on this research article published on tug.org from back in 2006 ([link](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87fahmy.pdf)).

- Does there exist a more modern/better approach, using `ConTeXt` (or `LuaLaTex`/`XeLaTeX` maybe w. `harfbuzz`), to get the same/better results?

I'm specific interested in typesetting this part from the research pager, that is in the Arabic font 'Amiri' ([link](https://www.amirifont.org/)) (in the words of the typeface designer, quote: *"a digital typeface to be used in typesetting Koranic verses."*):

[image]

Notes:

- The solution should provide options for individual letter/mark/vowel colouring
- Open regarding alternative typefaces, however they explicit need to typeset all the mark/vowels of classic/traditional Arabic text (like the Quran)
- Only text-based solution (the numbering between verses are not necessary)

---

Comment: Note that the coloring in that article is hard-coded/fixed for the special case of the language as used in the Quran, and the article remarks that "Such a hard-coded/programmatic way is not suitable for arbitary coloring that the user may wish to introduce into regular text outside of Qur'anic quotations." I suspect, although I might be wrong, that coloring individual marks and character elements arbitrarily is still not feasible with modern approaches.

Comment: you tagged the question with arabluatex. Did you actually checked its documentation? Beside arabluatex there is also the rather new option of a luatex with harfbuzz, this image has been made with it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpoO7.jpg.

Comment: @Marijn Agree, and other ticks here on TEXSE proves this to be the case, that is with working solutions for both ```arabluatex``` for LuaLaTeX and ```arabtex``` for ```pdfLaTeX```. I haven't been able to track a solution for the colouring off marks/vowels seperat with XeLaTeX, see this open tick [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/502023/192642).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer p. 56, section "11.5 Quran" [link](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/luatex/latex/arabluatex/arabluatex.pdf) of the documentation partly talks about this, however it's a bit more complicated than that. The ```\usepackage[nopar]{quran}``` only represents the _Hafs_ version of the text above

Comment: @imdk4242 You may also want to check the documentation on pp. 32-35 (sect. 6).  Actually the information is rather disseminated. As to hafbuzz, it looks very promising.

Comment: With `context` this answer can be helpful
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46240/54817